# Is My Output correct?

Tags: java, inheritance

Is the following output for each constructor correct?

```
class Blue {

    public Blue() {
        System.out.println("Bird");
    }

    public Blue(int i) {
    }
}

class Red extends Blue {

    public Red() {
        super(123);
        System.out.println("Dog");
    }
}

class White extends Red {

    public White() {
        System.out.println("Cat");
    }
}

class Orange extends White {

    public Orange() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Cow");
    }
}
```

So far,  `new Blue()` will print "Cow, Cat, Dog", `new Red()` will print "Dog", `new White()` will print "Dog" and `new Orange()` will print "Bird". Does this looks right?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think he/she wants to know how to write the main()

Comment: *"Does this looks right?"* - No

Comment: Why would `new Blue()` print "Cow, Cat, Dog"?

Comment: I am just getting confused on how to test this code? How do I write the main to see the output. When I did it, these are the answers I got, Which I think are not right. Thanks

Comment: I use [beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/download.html) to interactively test java code. Its easier than creating a new file and compiling it when I just want to test some java behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

The basic solution would be to create a new class, maybe called `Main`, from there, create the `public static void main(String args[])` method and simply create a new instance of each object...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new    Blue();
        System.out.println("...");
        new Red();
        System.out.println("...");
        new White();
        System.out.println("...");
        new Orange();
    }

}
```

If you're using an IDE, you would then simply be able to run this class and see the output...

Comment: Thank you for your response. So after I did that. I got way different outputs than the ones I had before. new Blue() will print "Bird", new Red() will print "Dog", new White() will print "Dog, Cat" and new Orange() will print "Dog, Cat, Cow". Is this output better?

Comment: If that's what the output says, then yes...